# Fix button styling on CSS hover?

Tags: javascript, css, vuetify.js

In this [codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/YzXQNpJ), I've created a graphic that looks like a left-pointing arrow by superimposing a 90° rotated square over the end of a rectangle.

However, when I hover over it, only the rectangular button itself changes its background color, not the rotated square and it looks awkward.

[image]

How can I make them both change simultaneously when hovering?

I tried setting up the `:hover` on the class and setting the color to the default color but hides the text.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {

    }
  }
})
```

```css
.myButton {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-right: none;
  width: 240px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.myButton:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -17.25px -119.5px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #FF7319;
  content: ''
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-flex xs3>
        <v-btn color="#FF7319" class="myButton">+My Button</v-btn>
      </v-flex>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: If I got your question right, I guess this is not border issue, its your component seems to have another element with a darker color, that makes the main button color to look like a border.

Comment: Please try to ask clearer questions and take more time to prepare them to make them unambiguous with crisp in definitions for people so you don't waste people's time with unnecessary guess work. I figured out what you want and cleaned up the question, but please learn from it.

Comment: Also knowing whether my answer is what you're looking for or not would be nice. I'm not the happiest with it, but best solution I could come up with without digging through the vue.js library for their default button UX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your library is automatically applying a hover effect to the button, I mimicked it for you best I could:

```
.myButton:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    margin: -17.25px -119.5px;
    width: 35px; 
    height: 35px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: #FF7319;
    content: '';
}
.myButton:hover{
  transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
}
.myButton:hover:after{
  box-shadow:  rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0 0 0 100px inset;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Only changes are in css. Might want to tweak the transitions some for timing, still looks a little off to me.

EDIT: I also made the height of the after pseudo element 34.4px in the code pen because it lined up better for me there - reverted back to your 35px original.

Comment: Accepting this as an answer. I guess it gives me a good idea where to look for the solution.

Comment: I don't know, but in trial and error testing it seemed that the inset box-shadow triggers on the :after element after the initial elements box-shadow animation begins. That's why I offset the transition speed. You can find the portion in vue.js that modifies this button, and compare the css there with this/add this there - but also make better choices about how to integrate these changes once you see that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with vue.js but if you haven't looked here, I'd try this: https://v1.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons